# How to get the output of the final layer of the model in CNTK?

Tags: cntk

How do I get the output of the model?
I'm writing a classifier using CNTK, and I want to print out the probability distribution (final output) so I can manually evaluate my results. How can I do that?

Right now, for evaluation, I use evaluation methods provided in CNTK, which doesn't require me to get the output of the model.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a model function (z). You can convert the model output to probabilities using the softmax function.

`C.softmax(z).eval()`.

You can pass the necessary data in the eval function.

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question,  I did  print(C.softmax(model).eval(data))", but it gave me error "Function::Forward provided values for (1) extra arguments which are not required for evaluating the specified Function outputs!".  When I delete "data", I'll get a runtime error. Why is that?

Comment: You can print the shape of a CNTK parameter. The eval function would return a numpy array or a list. Say x is input variable, output of the model is z(x). You can print C.softmax(z(x)).shape

Comment: Hi Sayan, thanks again! I got how to print out the shape now! Does the "Forward ... " error (I noted above) matter?

Comment: you can name any layer of your model. You can then print z.mylayername.shape